# how to count values inside of an array and convert them into a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I have a program that returns a set of ages inside of an array and I want to count them and put them inside of a dictionary, I have tried the following but no results. Please help!

let's say I have an array as follows:

```
ages = [20,20,11,12,10,11,15]
# count ages inside of array, I tried this
 for i in set(ages):
     if i in ages:
         print (ages.count(i))
# result returns the following
  1
  2
  1
  1
  2
```

this makes perfect sense as if we look at the set(ages) it equals = {10,11,12,15,20}

so the returning count actually equals to the count of each value in ages

When I try to put in a variable though, it only appends the first number or it says it is not iterable!
How can I store it into a list, even better how can I make dictionary containing the set(ages) and the count for each of the set(ages)

Thank you

Comment: You can use counter for it https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: Thank you, but I am trying to do it manually without libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to achieve this.  The first, and likely easiest, is to import the `Counter` class from `collections`.

```
from collections import Counter
ages = [20,20,11,12,10,11,15]
counts = Counter(ages)
# Counter({10: 1, 11: 2, 12: 1, 15: 1, 20: 2})
# if you want to strictly be a dictionary you can do the following
counts = dict(Counter(ages))
```

The other way is to do it in a loop:

```
counts = {}
for a in ages:
  # if the age is already in the dicitonary, increment it, 
  # otherwise, set it to 1 (first time we are seeing it)
  counts[a] = counts[a] + 1 if a in counts else 1
```

And finally, [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).  It has really no advantage over the loop other than the fact that it's a single line.  You still end up iterating over each variable in the list:

```
counts = {a:ages.count(a) for a in ages}
```

---

Since you asked more about the [ternary operator](http://pythoncentral.io/one-line-if-statement-in-python-ternary-conditional-operator/), that loop is equivalent to saying:

```
counts = {}
for a in ages:
  # if the age is already in the dicitonary, increment it, 
  # otherwise, set it to 1 (first time we are seeing the number)
  if a in counts:
     counts[a] = counts[a] + 1 
     print("Already seen", a, " -- ", counts[a])
  else:
     counts[a] = 1
     print("First time seeing", a, " -- ", counts[a])
```

The ternary operator allows us to complete this pattern in a single line.  Lots of languages have it:

1. [C/C++/C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)
2. [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: great! I have a question, how could you use an if and else statement when setting a variable?

Comment: It's called the [ternary operator.](http://pythoncentral.io/one-line-if-statement-in-python-ternary-conditional-operator/)  It really just frees up some lines of code.  It's equivalent to doing `if a in counts: counts[a] = counts[a] + 1 else: counts[a] = 1`.

Comment: Isn't `import Counter from collections` invalid syntax?

Comment: Those are [set comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

Comment: It is, it should be from collections import Counter

Comment: Yep.  That's my bad.  Just edited.  Typed it out too fast.  And @JackHughes I'm fairly certain it's a dictionary comprehension.  It has keys and values.  Set comprehension would be creating a set object.

Comment: when you reference count[a] = count[a] + 1, I understand that count[a] means it should start at index 1 for a in anges, but what does the second statement actually do? I'm somewhat new to python, thank you @Jalepeno112

Comment: @Jalepeno112 Yes you are correct, I saw `set` in the question and jumped to conclusions.

Comment: It's all good.  I saw your comment and immediately assumed you must be right.

Comment: @MauricioCastaneda dictionaries have keys and values.  The dictionary you want has the ages from the list has keys, and the number of times those ages appear as the values.  So when we write `counts[a] = counts[a]+1`, that means take the value at key `a` and add one to it.  I'll add a `print` statement into that loop so you can see how it progresses.

Answer (score 2):

try this!

```
ages = [20,20,11,12,10,11,15]
dic = {x:ages.count(x) for x in ages}
print dic
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store counts, better you use Python dicts.

```
ages = [20,20,11,12,10,11,15]
age_counts={} #define dict
for i in ages:
    #if age_counts does not have i, set its count to 1
    #increment otherwise
    if not age_counts.has_key(i):
        age_counts[i]=1
    else:
        age_counts[i]+=1
#you can now have counts stored
for i in age_counts:
    print i, age_counts[i]
```